# How to ignore code duplication check in sonar?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Recently we started including SonarQube checks in our projects. We have to do a small enhancement in one Java file and unable to merge the change and failing due to code duplication because of the code that is already present in the file.

[image]

Is it possible to avoid duplicate check for one Java file alone.
I tried the following solutions:

1. Added `<sonar.cpd.exclusion>` in pom.xml under `<properties>` tag.

   ```xml
   <properties>
           <java.version>1.8</java.version>
           <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
           <sonar.cpd.exclusions>com/abc/cdef/xyz/schedule/AbcDefScheduler.java</sonar.cpd.exclusions>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Used `SuppressWarnings("all")` and `SuppressWarnings("ALL")`
3. We use azure-pipeline-maven.xml and not sonar.properties.
4. I'm unable to edit sonar UI as I have only developer, but still getting same error. I'm unable to figure out a solution for the past two days. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: the best thing to do is NOT ignoring it, but extract the duplicate code to methods. What's the use of using Sonar if you're going to ignore it anyway?

Comment: The value of that `sonar.cpd.exclusions` doesn't look correct to me. Please provide that _actual_ value, or if you have to anonymize, do it in a way that it remains structurally and syntactically valid.

Comment: @Stultuske: There are around 750 lines of code and tried refractoring code to some extent.But still the percentage is not coming below 10%.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : <sonar.cpd.exclusions>com/abc/cdef/xyz/schedule/AbcDefScheduler.java</sonar.cpd.exclusions>

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : Can you please check if this is correct?